# Is there a way to listen to FragmentTransactions of a FragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an app with several `Fragments` which interact to each other. Sometimes I have to add a `Fragment`, sometimes I replace it.

**Is there a way to listen to FragmentTransactions completed, so I can keep track of every time a Fragment is added/shown/replaced?**

I've tried `fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener()` but unsuccessfully.

I thought of doing something on the `onResume()` of all of them, but if the app goes to background and foreground I should not do anything to my UI. Only when I interact between them.

Any help/strategy is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The reason is that I have an overlay that will be shown in the current Fragment. If the user navigates to any other Fragment, I need this overlay to disappear.

Comment: I honestly don't get why people just down vote a question without providing any feedback on regards to that.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly you do not need to listen to know this everytime - you just need to know that in regards of your application. If so, write `FragmentHelper` class (or add some methods to your Base fragment class if you have any) and wrap `FragmentManager` methods with it, incl. all the additional logic, tracking or everything else you require there.

Comment: I have an overlay that will be shown in the current Fragment. If the user navigates to any other Fragment, I need this overlay to disappear. That's why I think I need to be aware of all the Transactions. I'll take a look at what you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Is a custom overlay that I have to add manually, hence also remove manually

Comment: Unless I miss something about this overlay, this looks completely irrelevant. It is your activity, and it host the fragments

Comment: I have an Activity with about 5 Fragments interacting in many ways. I had an 'overlay' (a view) on one Fragment, and now my client requires me to show it on whatever is the current Fragment, but it must be shown only once. So I need o manage it manually and wanted a simple/high level manner to do it. I don't see why it's irrelevant

Comment: Then rework your activity's layout. Put both your overlay and fragment container in i.e. `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` (whereve overlay will be, well... over fragment container) and relieve fragments from a need of dealing with it. If you all done correctly, then your activity manages fragments anyway, so there will be no problem managing overlay

Comment: I have many callbacks from Fragments to the Activity to add/replace/show Fragments, and it's a lot of work to check everyone of them. Anyway, it became a useless discussion as there is no way to do what I intended to. I hope you at least understood what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

[**`FragmentManager.BackStackEntry`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) and pay attention to [**`getName()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html#getName%28%) by keeping reference to it in an array, and whenever `onBackStackChanged()` is called you will then know who has been removed or added.

Logic.edit

```
ArrayList<String> myNames; //will contain the tag id
// when onbackstackchanged is triggered
// get the one on top with getBackstackEntryAt(lastpos).getName()
//use that to check myNames.contains(String)
// i guess you can now put your logic in an if else statement
```